# How to hide (sub)section name at current page while it is still present in the table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

I write quite long document `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}`
where I include pages from **other.pdf** like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
...
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
...
\section{My pictures}   %1
\subsection{Description} %1.1
Some short description
\clearpage

\subsection{Picture of me} %1.2
\begin{figure}
\includepdf[pages=1,scale=1, noautoscale]{other.pdf}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
```

And what I would like to achieve is:
In the **table of contents** I would like to have all subsection listed:

```
1. My pictures
  1.1. Description
  1.2. Picture of me
```

But on the page with **Picture of me** I don't want to see this subtitle.
I tried many things but w/o any good result.
It could be resolved with some trick like font size 0, or total text width 0...
Just to achieve the desired result. Of course, for a proper solution, I will be so grateful.

What is also important is that included pages must have 100% of actual size and fill all page.

Comment: `\refstepcounter{subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection} Picture of me}` instead of `\szbsection{Picture of me}` should sork.

Comment: It works!! So so so much thank you. I will create a \newcommand using this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\refstepcounter{subsection} \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}Picture of me}` or define your own command as shown in the following MWE.
In this example code, I also included `\phantomsection` from the `hyperref` package. If you don't use this package, simply remove `\phantomsection` from the definition of `\myhiddensubsection`.

Side note: I also removed the `figure` environment since I assume you don't actually want the image/pdf file to float away from where it was used in the code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\myhiddensubsection}[1]{%
    \phantomsection%
    \refstepcounter{subsection}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\protect\numberline{\thesubsection}#1}%
    }
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{My pictures}
\subsection{Description} 
Some short description
\clearpage

\myhiddensubsection{Picture of me}


\includegraphics{example-image}

\clearpage

\subsection{next subsection} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just remove the space just before #1. This space appears in ToC and titles are not aligned with those not-hidden.

Comment: @pi.314: Thanks for pointing this out. I totally overlooked the extra space.